# Counterexample to Leibniz criterion for alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have this statement and I need to say if it is true or false:

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a real sequence.

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n = 0 \quad \implies \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n \quad \text{converges}$$

I know, from the Leibniz criterion that:

> If $a_n \to 0$, $a_n$ is decreasing and positive then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converges

From this fact I believe that the statement is false but I couldn't come up with an infinitesimal sequence that isn't decreasing and for that reason is divergent. I tried some function with $sin(\frac{1}{n})$ without any luck.
Any help would be very appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mark Viola gave a very natural example. Here is another one, where $a_n>0$ for all $n$: take
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}1/n,&\ n\ \text{ odd}\\ \ \\
1/n^2,&\ \text{ $n$ even } 
\end{cases}
$$

As Mark mentioned, instead of $1/n$, one may take $a_n$ where $\{a_n\}$ are terms that go to zero but their series diverges, and instead of $1/n^2$ one may take $b_n$, where $\{b_n\}$ is any  sequence such that their series converges.

Comment: Indeed.  And in fact, the $1/n^2$ part could be replaced with any terms that lead to a convergent series. (+1)

Comment: Of course. I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is a neat example

Answer (score 31):

HINT:

What happens if $a_n=(-1)^n\frac1n$?

Comment: This was just so simple that i could not think of it. Thank you very much, i feel a bit dumb ahah

Comment: You're welcome.  And don't feel bad.  Is there a learning point/takeaway, other than the counterexample itself, you can see that might be helpful?

Comment: No, thank you, i wasn't only able to find a counterexample!

Answer (score 7):

Consider $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\frac1n$...

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^na_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty-\frac1n=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=-\infty$...