# Find a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n$ does not converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n$ does not converge. Furthermore, the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ should converge to $0$ and also $a_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

I have tried some sequences and came to the following: Let's set $$a_n=\frac{1}{\log(n+1)}$$

Mathematica says that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ does not converge. But I don't know how to prove this and I can't finde another counter example. Maybe someone here can help?

Also something important: Shouldn't my $a_n$ not work because technically the Leibniz criterion guarantees the convergence? The only condition I could use in my $a_n$ according to this criterion would be to choose a sequence that is not monotonuous.

---

As pointed out in the comments I will try the following counter-example: $$a_n=\begin{cases}1/n,& n\text{ odd }\\1/n^2,&n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$With this I obtain $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^na_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{2n}a_{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{2n+1}a_{2n+1}=\\=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{8}(8-\pi^2)$$ which diverges because of the harmonic series. Now I just need to figure out why $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{8}(\pi^2-8)$$

Comment: Are you sure?  That should converge by the alternating series test pretty easily.

Comment: @Randall Yes, I forgot to add this important side note. Probably I'm using some wrong syntax in mathematica.

Comment: You are right, if an example exists it will have to be non-monotone.

Comment: And since you have alternating signs, it is very tempting to construct $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ separately.

Comment: You may try to alternate $1/n$ and $-1/\sqrt(n)$

Comment: @DanielFischer That's exactly what I tried. But I always end up with something that converges. I'd probably have to choose the $(a_{2n})$-part way "bigger" than the "$(a_{2n+1})$"-part which carries a negative sign.

Comment: Here is an example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2631916/42969.

Comment: the harmonic series where $a_n = 1/n$ diverges in the vanilla case.  So it should be made worse by your $(-1)^n$ term.  Try that choice for $a_n$

Comment: @MartinR You are very good at finding similar questions

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Here,  a Google search for “leibniz criterion counter example” was good enough :)

Comment: I have edited my question because in the linked post there weren't descriptions as to why the given examples are counter examples. Are my thoughts correct? I don't know if I can split the sum into two other sums and change the order of the summands like that.

Comment: @Buh You have to be very careful when splitting divergent sums like that. Also, the last sum in your question is a result of the [Basel problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)

Comment: It might be easier to bound the partial sums from below by something like $$\frac12\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n$$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch So what I did is not correct?

Comment: @Buh Your argument is not a formal argument (since you are technically working with undefined symbols). However, there is a straightforward formalisation of your argument using partial sums. If you are aware of this formalisation then it is fair to say that you did everything correctly

Comment: Otherwise it is false to split sums like this in general

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Yeah, I'm not really familiar with the formalism you mentioned so I have to look into that again. Thanks for clarifying though!

Comment: Here is my „formal interpretation“: Let $S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{2N} a_n$ be the $2N$th partial sum. Then $$S_N\geq 1-\frac{\pi^2}8+\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n,$$ which diverges as $N\to\infty$. (By the way, the exact value $1-\frac{\pi^2}8$ is not so important but rather only that this series converges.)